# Replacing dictionary value with mapped value from second dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I'm looking to replace the value in the first dictionary if there is a mapped value in the second and the field is empty in the first dictionary.

```py
dict1 = {'country': '', 'state': 'Arizona'}
dict2 = {'state': 'Arizona', 'country_mapping': United States}
```

If 'country' is empty in dict1 and there is a state match in dict2 then I want to replace 'country' in dict1 with the 'country_mapping' in dict2 so it would look like

```
dict1 = {'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Arizona'}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do? It seems unlikely to me that your data structures contain only one state, and I'm not sure what your more realistic setup is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on python version >= 3.7

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if v == '':
        mapping_str = f'{k}_mapping'
        if new_v := dict2.get(mapping_str):
            dict1[k] = new_v
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the country of first dict is empty string `''`, and value for `state` in both the dictionaries match, then assign country from the second dictionary to the first.

```py
if dict1['country']=='' and dict2['state']==dict1['state']:
    dict1['country'] = dict2['country_mapping']
print(dict1)
#output
{'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Arizona'}
```